# Proof that $\Bbb R[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that $\Bbb R[x] / \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \simeq \Bbb C$, so note that $x^2+1$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, so $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/ \langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is a field, in fact, is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$ of degree $2$.

It seems that from this it is possible to establish the isomorphism relation, but I don't see how to continue; any suggestions?

Comment: The equivalence class for $x$ corresponds to $i$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner so the possible isomorphism can be defined from $\phi:\ \Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1) \rightarrow \Bbb C$, by $\phi(a+bx)=a+bi$ or something like this?

Comment: That is correct